# Слово "грохнути" - літературне?

Tags: вживання-слів, дієслова

У [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghrokhnuty) такого слова немає, однак в [орфографічному словнику](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8) воно наявне:

> **грохнути** - дієслово, доконаний вид

Отож це слово літературне?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Знаходимо [**грохнути**](http://nauka-online.org/content/ukrayinskyy-komp-yuternyy-slenh) як сленгове слово (комп'ютерний сленг):

> **Грохнути** — видалити інформацію.

Також в ["МАТЕРІАЛАХ ДО «СЛОВНИКА ПОЛОНІЗМІВ У СХІДНОПОДІЛЬСЬКИХ ГОВІРКАХ» Тищенка Т.М.](https://dspace.udpu.edu.ua/jspui/bitstream/6789/1677/1/materialudoslovnukapolonizmiv.pdf) знаходимо:

> **Грохнути** г|рохнути ‘розбити’.

Отже, це слово не є нормативним в українській мові.